# ReleaseHoldAll in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, delay

I want to assign values to variables (like c for speed of light or G for gravitational constant) but have formulas calculated symbolically until last step.

How is it possible to do this in shortest way?

Replace is very long and duplicating while HoldForm can require multiple RealeaseHold if nested.

Is there some other functions for this?

Comment: You might be interested to know that there is a [new StackExchange site just for Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). It is not considered good form to post the same question in two StackExchange sites, but feel free to post future questions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can define `N` values for our constants.  For example:

```
N[c] = 299792458;
```

This defines a numerical value for `c`.  We can define a function that uses the constant:

```
f[v_] := Sqrt[1-v^2/c^2]
```

When we evaluate this function normally, it leaves `c` in symbolic form:

```
In[11]:= f[200000000]

Out[11]= Sqrt[1 - 40000000000000000/c^2]
```

But if we apply `N`, then `c` gets evaluated numerically:

```
In[12]:= f[200000000] // N

Out[12]= 0.744943
```

Comment: this is great. And is it possible to make N behave like it behaves with numbers, i.e. stop holding exact values if unexact already present in formula like in `2/34.0`?

Comment: @SuzanCioc Could you please give an example of an expression whose value you would like to have change depending upon the presence of an inexact number?  Do you that mean `3 c` would remain unchanged but `3.0 c` would evaluate to `8.99377*^8`?

Answer (score 2):

an example will help. But if I understood you, then you have

```
expr=9 c + 10 gravity
```

then you can write

```
expr /. {c -> 299792458, gravity -> 9.8}
```

to evaluate the symbolic expression with new values for the symbols involved.

The expression can remain symbolic all the time, and you can simply evaluates it for different values for the symbols in it.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now. But I was hoping this can be done some other way, for example with `//N` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question has two parts.

(1) Whether we should force Mathematica to do all calculations symbolically.  This is (almost always) wrong.  Mathematica can do arbitrary precision numerics, so we should prefer to tell it the precision of our physical constants (when they exceed `$MachinePrecision`) and let it choose the most efficient way to solve the problem.

(2) How do we print intermediate steps in symbolic form.  For this, use `HoldForm[expr]`, and then

```
expr //. HoldForm[x_]:>ReleaseHold[HoldForm[x]]
```

should give you the evaluation results as you indicate.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a "ReleaseHoldAll" function, `MapAll` (short form `//@`) maps a function to all parts of an expression.  Therefore, you can use:

```
ReleaseHold //@ expr
```

where `expr` is your expression containing `Hold`, `HoldForm`, etc., at any level.

Answer (score 0):

There are strange attributes to using the replacement operator in mathematica sometimes. This has to do with the context in which you apply it. The above answer will probably work well, but personally I always use Block[{variable=number}, code] command, which makes the variables act as global within the Block brackets, but once the evaluation proceeded outside, the variables remain undeclared.

use it like this:

```
Block[{c = 299792458, gravity = 9.0 }, answer = 9 c + 10 gravity ]
```

gives output:

```
2.69813*10^9
```

and also sets answer globally to the value of the output so you can use it after :

```
answer/2
```

results in:

```
1.34907*10^9
```